# Failed install after installing Myysql-python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Problem using MySQLdb after installing MySQLdb-python.  I followed the instructions I followed the instruction that had me delete the build and delete the egg then modify the my_config and then run the install again.  I also tried installing the 64 bit version still no luck

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nick.leclair/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/Tester/driveByScript.py",     line 1, in <module>
import MySQLdb
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/_mysql.py", line 4, in __bootstrap__
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py",    line 882, in resource_filenameself, resource_name
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1351, in get_resource_filename   self._extract_resource(manager,self._eager_to_zip(name))
File     "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1382, in _extract_resource outf, tmpnam = _mkstemp(".$extract", dir=os.path.dirname(real_path))
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2576, in _mkstemp
from tempfile import mkstemp
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py",      line 35, in <module>

ImportError: cannot import name Random
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it was problem with Aptana not picking up the new library.